# Segfault when creating object in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

`Card.h`:

```
#include <string>

class Card
{
    public:
        enum suits {Spades, Diamonds, Hearts, Clubs};
        Card(int _suit, int _value);
        std::string SuitToString(int suitidx);
        Card();
        ~Card();
    private:
        int value;
        std::string suit;
};
```

`Card.cpp`:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Card.h"

Card::Card() {
}

Card::Card(int _suit, int _value)
{
    this->suit=SuitToString(_suit);
    this->value=_value;
}

Card::~Card()
{
}

std::string Card::SuitToString(int suitidx)
{
    std::vector<std::string> suitStrings = {"Club", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};

    return suitStrings[suitidx];
}
```

`Deck.h`:

```
#include "Card.h"
#include <vector>

class Deck: public Card {
    public:
        Deck();
        ~Deck();

};
```

`Deck.cpp`:

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include <vector>

Deck::Deck()
{
    for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<14; j++) {
            Card c(i,j);
            AddCard(c);
        }
    }
}

Deck::~Deck()
{
}
```

and `main.cpp`:

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Deck d;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run this, I get a seg fault. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Counting starts at `0` in C++.

Comment: You don't need `Card ` to be base class of `Deck`.

Comment: Did you mean 'std::cout << d.DeckSize() << endl;'?

Comment: Ok I am not familiar with this and interested: `d.DeckSize()` gives us an `int`, how is the `<<`-operator defined for int? What should this line do? `d.DeckSize()<<endl;`

Comment: @generic_opto_guy Knowing C++, it will convert `endl` to a `bool`, which will be converted to an `int` value of `1`. So you'll effectively end up with `d.DeckSize() << 1`. That left shits the number and the result is discarded.

Comment: `d.DeckSize()<<endl;` should generate error. At least it does for me in *gcc*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tkausl is right, your Problem is in the `SuitToString`-Method. You call this with an invalid index.